# Jquery/rss feed script to filter out all the posts older than 90 days

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss

I am creating a script to display my rss feed and filter out the older posts, all with Jquery. In my script, I am trying to filter out posts older than 90 days.

There is 1 post displaying that is past the 90 day limit. I tried changing my tags, using different parameters.

What I am missing or added that shouldn't be there?

My Jquery code is:

```
<script>
//function to load XML document    
$.ajax({
    type:       'GET',
    url:        '/ser/whatsnew_main.xml',
    dataType:   'xml',
    success:    function(xml){
        $(xml).find("item").each(function(){
        var title = $(this).find('title').text();
        var date = $(this).find('pubDate').text();
        var description = $(this).find('description').text();
        $('#feed').append('<li><strong>'+title+'</strong><br>'+date+'<br>'+description+'</li>');    

        //exp date parameters
        var today = new Date();
        var runOn = new Date(today.setDate(1));
        var expire = new Date(runOn.setDate(-90));
        var pub = new Date(date);           
            if(today.getDate() === 1 == true && pub < expire == true){          
            $(this).each('item').empty();   
            }
            else if(pub < expire == true){
                $(this).each('item').empty();
                }
                alert("on " +today.getDate()+ ", expiration date is " +expire);
        });         
        }
        });     

</script>
```

I tried using the current date for `if(today.getDate() === 26 == true && pub>expire == false)`, I tried `if(today.getDate()=== 26 == true && pub<expire == false)`, `if(today.getDate()=== 26 == true && pub<expire == true)`, `if(today.getDate()=== 26 == true && pub>expire == true)`, and either all the posts show up or that 1 post that is past 90 days shows up along with the newer posts.

FYI, when I run the alert, the `today.getDate() = 1` as in the 1st of the month, and `expire = Oct 2 2015`, so don't know why the Sep 30 2015 post keeps showing up.

**Update** - my xml code is (w/o the `<xml>`, `<rss>` & `<channel>` tags):

```
<item class="combo">
    <title>Generic Title</title>
    <pubDate>28 Oct 2015</pubDate>
    <description><![CDATA[Content <a href="/file.htm">some link</a>.]]></description>
    </item>

    <item class="class">
      <title>Gen title</title>
      <pubDate>30 Sep 2015</pubDate>      
      <description><![CDATA[Some more content <a href="/file2.htm#anchor">another link</a>.]]></description>
    </item>
```

I tried the same code on other rss feeds, but it's that last outdated post that keeps showing up, no matter if it's dated 30 Sep 2015 or 21 Aug 2015.

I don't want to create a whole new function, have it called from the 1st function and create a whole new xml load function just to get the pubDate.

Comment: would be helpful to see the actual feed data for a few of the items, including the one that shouldn't be showing up.

Comment: Please try to simplify the code, the evaluation of === and == already is a boolean, something like...if (today.getDate() == 26 && runOn > expire)

Comment: @Chris OnDaRocks, after trying your suggestion, my code displays all of the postings if I don't add that '== true' to both booleans. For some reason, it's wants it there. I also tried your suggestion with the '== true' & '==false', and '==true' & '==true', changing the > back and forth, since the code wasn't working, and still all the posts show. I guess my next option is to create a separate function and have it called after the end of first function. But that means I might have to do the whole xml load thing just to get the pubDates. :|

Comment: @adammtlx, a sample of my xml code is - not with the beg <xml>, <rss> &<channel> tags: '<item class="combo">
 <title>Generic Title</title>
 <pubDate>28 Oct 2015</pubDate>
 <description><![CDATA[Content <a href="/file.htm">some link</a>.]]></description>
 </item>
 
 <item class="dea">
      <title>Gen title</title>
      <pubDate>30 Sep 2015</pubDate>      
      <description><![CDATA[Content <a href="/file.htm#anchor">another link</a>.]]></description>
    </item>' I am having probs removing the very last expired posting, in this case, the 1 dated 30 Sep 2015. The other older ones are removed.

Comment: @ChrisOnDaRocks, I left off the '==true' part on both of them, and they work, but not with 'runOn>expire'. Right now I'm using 'if(today.getDate() == 26 && pub < expire)'. All of the older postings are gone, except for that last one. I wanna keep my code simple & neat, but it's wanting me to take a more difficult approach. Any other suggestions? Would greatly be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear to me what you're trying to do given the logic you have, but if all you're interested in doing is removing the expired elements from the XML data feed, you should be able to do it how you have it once you fix a couple things, like this:

```
if(today.getDate() === 1 && pub < expire) {          
    $(this).remove();   
} else if(pub < expire) {
    $(this).remove();
}
```

From what I can tell it seems you have messed up the logic with this statement:

```
$(this).each('item').empty();
```

$(this) refers to the current item in the feed, but then you're trying to ask it for each "item" inside of it and then you're trying to empty each "item" inside of the current item of its contents as opposed to removing the item itself.

Here's a JSFiddle with the items as HTML instead of XML, but it seems to do what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/eL6s268r/1/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see the problem, but I think is not in the conditional, I see you are setting Today to be the first the day of the month while you are creating runOn, so in the beginning of your code, instead of this:

```
var today = new Date();
var runOn = new Date(today.setDate(1));
```

try this code:

```
var today = new Date();
var runOn = new Date();
runOn.setDate(1);
```

Comment: Ty for helping me out. I tried both of your suggestions, and even played around with it, and it still won't show up. I finally came up with this and it still displays the the last past due update: 'var today = new Date();
  var runOn = new Date();
  var expire = new Date(runOn.setDate(-90));
  var pub = new Date(date);
  runOn.setDate(1);
  console.log(pub<expire);   
  if(today.getDate() == 1 && pub < expire){   
  $(this).each('item').empty(); 
  }
  else if(pub < expire){
  $(this).each('item').remove();
  }' for some reason, the page wants me to define the 'item' and .remove() doesn't work

Comment: hence me using .empty() instead. I'm using an template that has been tampered with a lot, and am guessing that there is a conflict somewhere in one of the many scripts it's using and that's why it keeps displaying the last post, which is expired. The console log does say 8 false and 10 true, however it keeps displaying 9 posts instead of the 8 false posts. IDK what I'm gonna do.. Wish I had a clean template to work with, but this is what was given to me..

Comment: Hi Chris, I applied the examples you sent, the last one worked wonderfully, however, the last expired date came up as false, even though it was true and supposed to be removed. IDK what's going on with this. All the examples worked well in jsfiddle, but it acts differently on the actual page. Problem is, my job won't let me start a new template b/c there's code that needs to be there. Maybe I can find something that will take the last posting off, regardless of the date. Have to do some more research, oh well.